# How can I get repositories domains from a composer.json to setup iptables?

Tags: composer-php, iptables

I want to list all the domains that my composer.json will use to download dependencies of my project in order to list them in my iptable config. Is there a way to do this ?

This is the part of my iptable config I want to complete with that list :

```
HTTPS_SERVERS=(packagist.org api.github.com github.com getcomposer.org us3.api.mailchimp.com mandrillapp.com)
for i in `seq 0 $((${#HTTPS_SERVERS[*]} -1))`
do
  server=${HTTPS_SERVERS[i]}
  $IPT -A me_bad -p tcp -d $server --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  $IPT -A bad_me -p tcp -s $server --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done
```

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are doing it for some security-related setting on your production server, I'd suggest you search for a better deployment tool instead of using Composer on the production server. There is no need on a prod machine to host dev tools like Git, SVN, and have access to e.g. Github (which allows access to probably any software to download you can think of).

Comment: I do not use composer to deploy, but to keep dependencies consistent (what it is built for in fact). When your app relies on hundreds of dependencies like any framework, it doesn't make any sense to put all of them in your GIT imo.

By the way I use capistrano to deploy :)

Comment: But why do you want to add several composer-related domains into iptables?

Comment: "Drop all first" philosophy :)
I want to control every single network connection, even outgoing ones, so I start my rules by droping everything and after I allow what I really need.

Comment: Ok, obviously you want to do that, but where is the security? Composer has yet to implement things like package signing and secure transmission, so everyone who is able to inject the domain he needs to penetrate your firewall into any package you use will succeed unless you manually inspect all domains involved. And then you still have to verify that these manually whitelisted domains don't get tampered with. So you don't use the domain name for the iptables, but the current IP addresses - which will constantly require updates if the domain points to a different address someday.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't want to build a "automatic" list from my composer.json, I just wanted to know if there was a simple way of knowing each domains involved with my composer.json in order to check them manually and put them or not in my iptable.

I already fork packages that I don't trust on my own repository to prevent external code injection.

Never mind, I solved my problem, classic way ;)

1/ Run composer
2/ find in wich package it hangs out
3/ find the domain
4/ if it can be trusted, add it to iptables, if not fork/clone
5/ Goto 1 :)

Thanks for your time sven.